# Rendering JavaScript breaks page navigation and reactive function in R Shiny DT (DataTable)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a datatable built with R Shiny, and rendering data dynamically using my reactive function, `filteredData()`. The data I'm bringing in from Azure SQL has a couple columns (indexes 3 and 29) that contain a lot of nvarchar text; this text screws up the visual aesthetic of the table and makes viewing multiple rows a pain. My solution was to limit the viewable text in these columns' cells to 200 characters, and display the rest as a tooltip on hover.

```
    output$table1 <- renderDT(
        DT::datatable(filteredData(),
                            selection = "single",
                            escape = FALSE,
                            style = "bootstrap4",
                            rownames = FALSE,
                            options = list(
                                dom = 'rtip',
                                scrollX=TRUE,
                                autoWidth = TRUE,
                                searching=FALSE,
                                ordering=TRUE,
                                bFilter = FALSE,
                                pageLength = 5,
                                columnDefs = list(list(
                                    targets = c(3, 28),
                                    width = '600px'
                                    # THIS BREAKS THE TABLE, CANNOT GO TO *NEXT* PAGE
                                    ,render = JS(
                                        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                                        "return type === 'display' && data.length > 200 ?",
                                        "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 200) + '...</span>' : data;",
                                        "}")
                                )))
        ))
```

This solution works (kind of). The text truncates and shows a tooltip on hover as expected, but subsequently breaks the built-in buttons that allows the user to go to the next or previous page in the data table (right now I'm limiting my datatable to 5 records per page). When I click 'next', a a small, semi-opaque window pops up in the middle of the screen and says, "processing", but is stuck in this loop. *It also breaks my reactive filtering of the data.* Commenting out the problematic Javascript

```
                                    #,render = JS(
                                    #    "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
                                    #    "return type === 'display' && data.length > 200 ?",
                                    #    "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 200) + '...</span>' : data;",
                                    #    "}")
```

fixes the page navigation but then I have no tooltips or text truncation. I've checked the documentation on DT's website, and don't understand what I'm doing differently, aside from my reactive, SQL-derived data.

EDIT: I'm using these packages, for what it's worth: `shinymanager`, `tidyverse`, `DT`, `bs4Dash`. I've also called `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` in my `dashboardBody()`.

Comment: It's always best to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). However, did you call `useShinyjs()`? It seems like that gets missed sometimes.

Comment: I'll try to create a reproducible example. But yes, I've called shinyjs::useShinyjs() in my dashboard body

Comment: Looking at the code now - wow, not sure why I thought this had anything to do with `shinyjs`. Yikes! When I add my own data frame and stick this into an existing shiny application, it works without an issue. Maybe your packages need to be updated? Check `DT` and `htmlwidgets`. I checked for library conflicts, as well. I didn't find any with the libraries you listed, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's going on, but you can try the **ellipsis** plugin:

```
library(DT) 

dat <- data.frame(
  A = c("fnufnufroufrcnoonfrncacfnouafc", "fanunfrpn frnpncfrurnucfrnupfenc"),
  B = c("DZDOPCDNAL DKODKPODPOKKPODZKPO", "AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN")
)

datatable(
  dat, 
  plugins = "ellipsis",
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(list(
      targets = c(1, 2),
      render = JS("$.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis( 200, false )")
    ))
  )
)
```

[image]